Proof diagonalization of rational numbers always results in a irrational number
I am aware that the diagonalization argument does not imply the rationals are uncountable as although the newly constructed number is not anywhere on the list, it is irrational. I am looking for a proof of this fact. Given any bijection $$F\colon \mathbf N \longrightarrow \mathbf Q \cap (0,1)$$ I define a new number D such that
$$D_n = \cases{3 & $F(n)_n \neq 3$ \cr 2 & $F(n)_n = 3$}$$
I want to show that D is irrational. I assume the proof would go something along the lines of "assume D has a repeating decimal expansion and show that this means F isn't a bijection". I am stuck with how to continue here.
I am aware that because F is a bijection and D is not in the range of F, D is necessarily irrational. However, I would like to prove it another way, preferably using the aforementioned proof by contradiction.
Any help would be appreciated.

Not sure what you are hoping for.  You need to use the fact that $F$ is bijective, else the claim need not be true.

@lulu I guess what i am trying to do is understand this page which claims the reason why the number must be irrational is that least common multiple of period lengths is unbounded. this is obviously true, however I fail to see why that implies the number being irrational.

Well...that appears to refer to an explicit bijection.  Of course, in that case you might well be able to see directly that the number you make is not rational.  Of course, that won't help you with the general claim.

I doubt you would be able to directly prove you get an irrational without any explicit information about $F$. I mean...how do you know $F$ doesn't have the property that $F(n)_n=3$ for all $n$? Well, because then the number with all $2$s isn't on the list.... The closest similar argument I can think of is the explicit proof that if you ennumerate the terminating rationals and apply the diagonal argument you get a non-terminating one (because there are too many rationals with "short" expansions), but that relies on explicit properties of $F$.

@ArturoMagidin I assume that F is a bijection. F(n)_n = 3 for all n is not a bijection. An equivalent problem would be "have F(n) be expressed in binary instead of decimal and prove that the diagonal of F is irrational." If the diagonal is irrational then applying diagonalization will also yield an irrational number(there are probably problems due to multiple representations though).

How do you know it is not a bijection? Because, knowing something about the values of $F$, you can exhibit a number that is not in the image. If you know nothing about the values of $F$, I doubt you will be able to show that the resulting number is not rational. The last two sentences of your comment are unintelligible to me.

The diagonalization argument uses a list of rationals and their decimal expansions, say
$$\begin{align*}
\newcommand{\r}[1]{r_{#1} &= d_{#1,0} \; . \; d_{#1,1} \, d_{#1,2} \, d_{#1,3} \, d_{#1,4} \cdots \\}
\r{0}
\r{1}
\r{2}
\r{3}
\vdots & \\
\r{n}
\vdots &
\end{align*}$$
where

$r_i \in \mathbb{Q}$
$d_{i,0} \in \mathbb{Z}$
$d_{i,n} \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,9\}$ for $n \ge 1$

A number $x$ is then defined by
$$\newcommand{\d}[1]{\widetilde{d_{#1,#1}}}
x := \d 0 \; . \; \d 1 \, \d 2 \,  \d 3 \, \cdots \, \d n \, \cdots
$$
where
$$
\d n \ne d_{n,n} \text{ for each } n
$$
Hence:

$x \ne r_0$, differing in the integer part
$x \ne r_1$, differing in the first decimal point
$x \ne r_2$, differing in the second decimal point
In general, $x \ne r_n$, as they differ in the $n$th decimal point

If the set of $r_i$ as a complete list of rationals, then $x \ne r_i$ for every rational $r_i$, and hence $x$ is not a rational number.
